# Docker - Port Forwarding for Psiturk Not working

Tags: docker, server, port, mturk

I'm new to docker and am stuck on correctly exposing ports for psiturk.

I have a docker-compose.yml file that creates a psiturk container, a nginx container, an adminer container, and a mysql container. I am attempting to run the psiturk experiment in sandbox mode on mTurk. The server cannot connect. I've exposed the ports. When I run psiturk outside of Docker, I can run an experiment in sandbox so it's not my computer's firewall.

I've heard of publishing exposed ports and attempted this by adding:

```
ports:
     - 22362:22362
```

to the psiturk container, but it didn't work.

For my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'

services:

  psiturk:
    container_name: my-experiment
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./exp:/exp
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    restart: unless-stopped

  nginx:
    container_name: my-experiment-nginx
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./exp:/var/www/exp:ro
      - ./default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    restart: unless-stopped

  db:
    container_name: my-experiment-db
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: anothersafepassword
      MYSQL_DATABASE: shared4data
      MYSQL_USER: jorja
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: totallysafepassword
    restart: unless-stopped

  adminer:
    container_name: my-experiment-adminer
    image: adminer:latest
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:8080:8080
```

For my dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6-stretch

LABEL maintainer="Jorja Shires <jshires@nevada.unr.edu>" version="1.0"

ENV PSITURK_GLOBAL_CONFIG_LOCATION "/exp"

WORKDIR "/exp"

RUN pip install \
        psiturk==2.3.8 \
        pymysql==0.10.0 \
        python-Levenshtein==0.12.0 \
    && rm -rf ~/.cache/pip

CMD ["bash"]

EXPOSE 22362
EXPOSE 80
```

For my psiturk config file:

```
[Server Parameters]
host = 0.0.0
port = 22362
cutoff_time = 30
logfile = server.log
loglevel = 2
debug = true
threads = auto
adserver_revproxy_host = MyStaticIPAddress
adserver_revproxy_port = 80 

[Shell Parameters]
launch_in_sandbox_mode = true
#bonus_message = "Thanks for participating!"
use_psiturk_ad_server = true
ad_location = false
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh hey, looks like you're using my experiment template: https://github.com/paxtonfitzpatrick/psiturk-experiment-template

I think there are two issues going on here:

1. In your `exp/config.txt` file, the "`host`" field is `0.0.0` but should be **`0.0.0.0`**.
2. There were updates made to both the psiTurk Python package and the psiTurk ad server (which hosts your `ad.html`) a few months ago that broke a lot of existing experiment setups. In particular, according to the psiTurk [README](https://github.com/NYUCCL/psiTurk/blob/master/README.md):

   > Versions less than v2.3.12 will not be able to post HITs due to a change implemented by the psiturk ad server's hosting provider.

   So the psiTurk version installed in your `Dockerfile` (2.3.8) will no longer work.  I'll update the experiment template repository soon, but the general steps to upgrade from the current version are:

   - in your `Dockerfile`, replace `psiturk==2.3.8` with `psiturk==2.3.12`
   - remove **all** comments from `exp/templates/ad.html` (for whatever reason, they cause issues with the updated ad server)
   - in `config.txt`, under `[Shell Parameters]`, make sure `use_psiturk_ad_server` is explicitly set to `true` and `ad_location` is explicitly set to `false`

It's also worth noting that psiTurk v3.0 has dropped support for the [psiturk.org](https://psiturk.org) ad server altogether, so it seems likely that at some point in the future, the psiTurk maintainers will simply stop managing it and you'll have to set up your own ad server ([the docs recommend Heroku](https://psiturk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html#no-more-secure-ad-server)).  But for now (and hopefully for a while yet!) the steps above should suffice.